# primefaces effect is not working

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am using JSF 2 and PrimeFaces 4.0. When I run `new.xhtml` file then it gives the following exception:

```
Error Rendering View[/NewFile.xhtml]: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.OutcomeTargetRenderer.getTargetURL(OutcomeTargetRenderer.java:80) [:4.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.button.ButtonRenderer.buildOnclick(ButtonRenderer.java:93) [:4.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.button.ButtonRenderer.encodeMarkup(ButtonRenderer.java:53) [:4.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.button.ButtonRenderer.encodeEnd(ButtonRenderer.java:32) [:4.0]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) [:2.1.1-FCS]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1763) [:2.1.1-FCS]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759) [:2.1.1-FCS]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759) [:2.1.1-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:401) [:2.1.1-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131) [:2.1.1-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121) [:2.1.1-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [:2.1.1-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [:2.1.1-FCS]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:410) [:2.1.1-FCS]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_17]

22:04:34,939 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/p1].[Faces Servlet]] Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.OutcomeTargetRenderer.getTargetURL(OutcomeTargetRenderer.java:80) [:4.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.button.ButtonRenderer.buildOnclick(ButtonRenderer.java:93) [:4.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.button.ButtonRenderer.encodeMarkup(ButtonRenderer.java:53) [:4.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.button.ButtonRenderer.encodeEnd(ButtonRenderer.java:32) [:4.0]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) [:2.1.1-FCS]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1763) [:2.1.1-FCS]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759) [:2.1.1-FCS]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759) [:2.1.1-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:401) [:2.1.1-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131) [:2.1.1-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121) [:2.1.1-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [:2.1.1-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [:2.1.1-FCS]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:410) [:2.1.1-FCS]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_17]
```

My web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>web</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My xhtml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/css/default.css" />
   <style type="text/css">
                .ui-widget{font-size:90% !important;}
                .ui-layout-unit-content{background-image:url('a.jpg');}
            </style>
 <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head" />


</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>Hello World PrimeFaces</h1>
    <p:inputText /> 
 <p:button outcome="productDetail" value="Bookmark" icon="ui-icon-star"></p:button>
</h:body>
</html>
```

I have been facing this problem for a week, but I'm unable to solve this.

Comment: isn't missing a form?

Comment: Missing form should be the cause. First point in this answer applies to your scenario. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183

Answer (score 1):

The only thing is that you need to do is just create as jsf page (xhtml page) with name "productDetail.xhtml" in the same directory where your current xhtml available.

Doing above will get your code to work, and yes put your enclose your code inside of h:body with h:form. Otherwise it will generate warning like below  (if javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE is set to Development),

```
The form component needs to have a UIForm in its ancestry. Suggestion: enclose the necessary components within <h:form>
```